# Magento export product problem

Tags: magento

Im using default profile for magento product export when i click the run profile i get a blank screen i have 1000 products in the db.
Import works like charm.
Also im not able to export the product stocks also,but im able to export customers.
Im using magento 1.4 version.
Please help

Comment: Turn on Magento exception logging. Turn on PHP error logging. Look in your logs, rept the errors you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If setting limits doesn't work I suggest turning on flat catalog or use sql. I provided a link-only answer that is now expired, but the WayBackMachine saved the day (http://web.archive.org/web/20110112232603/http://basdebie.com/magento/magento-export-time-out-try-plain-sql)

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.entity_id, P.sku, V.value AS Name, T1.value AS ProdDesc, T2.value AS ShortDesc,
V3.value AS MetaTitle, V4.value AS MetaDescription,
C2.value AS CatName,
D.value AS Price,
G.parent_id AS Product_parent,
    CASE
        WHEN V2.Value = 'no_selection'
        OR V2.Value = '/'
                THEN NULL
        ELSE V2.value
    END AS Image
    FROM  mgnt_catalog_product_entity AS P INNER JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_product_entity_varchar AS V  ON P.entity_id = V.entity_id  AND V.attribute_id  = 60  LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_product_entity_varchar AS V2 ON P.entity_id = V2.entity_id AND V2.attribute_id = 74  LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_product_entity_varchar AS V3 ON P.entity_id = V3.entity_id AND V3.attribute_id = 71  LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_product_entity_varchar AS V4 ON P.entity_id = V4.entity_id AND V4.attribute_id = 73  LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_category_product AS C1 ON P.entity_id = C1.product_id LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_category_entity_varchar AS C2 ON C1.category_id = C2.entity_id AND C2.attribute_id = 33 LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_product_relation AS G ON P.entity_id = G.child_id LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_product_entity_text    AS T1 ON P.entity_id = T1.entity_id AND T1.attribute_id = 61  LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_product_entity_text    AS T2 ON P.entity_id = T2.entity_id AND T2.attribute_id = 62  LEFT JOIN
    mgnt_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS D  ON P.entity_id = D.entity_id  AND D.attribute_id  = 64
ORDER BY P.entity_id ASC
```

Comment: And this is why link only answers are not appreciated on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

In your Magento directory is an .htaccess file. Open it and find the following lines:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Increase the `memory_limit` to `256M` or even higher if you like. Confirm the change by creating a file in your Magento directory that looks like this:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Access the file by typing it's name directly into your browser, you should be able to see what `memory_limit` is now.